# How to achieve this effect/layout in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, layout, scaffold

As I found out, this effect of searching is built in the ios framework. But how this layout can be implemented in Flutter?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably the [Hero](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations) widget

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_search_bar - looks like this is what you need, but unfortunately that package still not migrated to null safety, but you can look at source code and create own widget.